# background tileSprite is over sized

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm creating a simple platform game with the phaser framework. I've added to background images as tileSprites to provide a parallax background. They are both showing in game, however they are over sized, roughly double the height I expect.

- Sprite asset size - 2048 x 1024
- Game world size - 2400 x 1024

**Adding the tileSprite**

```
preload: function () {
    this.load.image('far-background', 'assets/far-background.png');
    this.load.image('near-background', 'assets/near-background.png');
},
create: function () {
    this.farBackground = this.add.tileSprite(0,0, 2400, 1024, 'far-background');
    this.nearBackground = this.add.tileSprite(0,0, 2400, 1024, 'near-background');
}
```

How do I make the tilesprites fill the canvas vertically?

Full code can be [found here](http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/sandbox/smoothiehunter/) if needed.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have (tile)sprites in the game that are too big, you can try using the `scale` property to manipulate their size: http://phaser.io/docs/2.2.2/Phaser.TileSprite.html#scale

Here is an example of using the `scale` property to manipulate a sprite's size: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/scale-a-sprite

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This did sort my problem. When I was placing it in game I realised that the game world was not as large as I thought......must of changing it during a sleepy session and forgot. DOH!